# How to fix problem with sorting data in html table from database?

Tags: php, html

I have this table

```
id  |  masina
1   |  1 bob cat
2   |  2 platforma
3   |  1 platforma
4   |  1 platforma
5   |  1 platforma
6   |  1 platforma
7   |  3 platforma
8   |  2 platforma
9   |  1 platforma
10  |  1 platforma
11  |  1 platforma
12  |  1 platforma
13  |  1 platforma
14  |  1 skip
```

I get distinct value of sting in column "masina" and display names of machines as header and then I take value of all machines and trying to display all values of "platforma" under header "platforma"... etc.

I want to sort it like this
[image]

But I have a problem with sorting and my sorting with while loop looks like this.
[image]

I don't know how to sort this correctly.
This is my code:

```
<table>
<thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="9" style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $mesecId; ?> (<?php echo $godinaId; ?>)</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <?php
        $sqlMasine1 = "SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(masina, INSTR(masina, ' ') + 1) AS machine_name FROM masine WHERE projekatId='$projekatId' ORDER BY id";
        $resultMasine1 = mysqli_query($con, $sqlMasine1);
        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultMasine1)) {
            ?>
            <th colspan="2"><?php echo $row1['machine_name']; ?></th>
            <th style="width: 10px; background-color: white;"></th>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php
        $sqlMasine2 = "SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(masina, INSTR(masina, ' ') + 1) AS machine_name FROM masine WHERE projekatId='$projekatId' ORDER BY id";
        $resultMasine2 = mysqli_query($con, $sqlMasine2);
        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultMasine2)) {
            ?>
            <td style="background-color: #e0ecff;">Dan</td>
            <td style="background-color: #ffadad;">Zbir</td>
            <td style="width: 10px;"></td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php
        $sqlMasine3 = "SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(masina, INSTR(masina, ' ') + 1) AS machine_name FROM masine WHERE projekatId='$projekatId' ORDER BY id";
        $resultMasine3 = mysqli_query($con, $sqlMasine3);
        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultMasine3)) {
            $query = "SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(masina, 1, INSTR(masina, ' ') - 1) AS UNSIGNED) AS machine_id FROM masine WHERE projekatId='$projekatId' AND SUBSTRING(masina, INSTR(masina, ' ') + 1) = '" . $row1['machine_name'] . "' ORDER BY id";
            $rezultat = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat)) {
                ?>
                <td style="background-color: #e0ecff;"></td>
                <td style="background-color: #ffadad;"><?php echo $row['machine_id']; ?></td>
                <td></td>
        <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```